# Trying to get property of non-object while reaching parents attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, parent-child, laravel-5.4, has-many

I got Trying to get property of non-object error on line: `<span>{{$item->subcats->name}}</span>`. How can I reach name of a subcat of a product?
my Product model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function subcats(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcat::class);
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
my Subcat Model:
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcat extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function cats(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Cat::class);
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
the blade is:
@extends('template.master')
@section('content')

        @forelse($product as $item)
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href="/product/{{$item->id}}">{{$item->title}}</a><br>
                <span class="caret">{{$item->description}}</span><br><br>
                <span>Price :</span><span class="caret">{{$item->price}}</span><br>

                 <span>{{$item->subcats->name}}</span> 
            </div>
        @empty
        @endforelse
@endsection
```

Comment: I think the error is in the line `{{$item->subcat->name}}`, since the relationship is called "subcats".

Comment: my bad! I post it wrong.the problem exist even by the right name.

Comment: Instead of `$this->belongsTo(Subcat::class)` try `$this->belongsTo('App/Subcat')`. Same with the other relationship definitions, and see what happens.

Comment: I did. same error.

Comment: How do you define your `$product` variable? Could you post the code?

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $comment = Comment::all();
        $product = Product::all();
        $cat = Cat::all();
        $subcat = Subcat::all();
        return view('template.index',['product'=>$product,'cat'=>$cat,'subcat'=>$subcat,'Comment'=>$comment]);
    }

Comment: As far as I could tell, it should work... Try this: `$product = Product::with('subcats')->all()`

Answer (score 0):

You are naming it wrong `{{ $item->subcats->name}}`

Comment: I did it.but this error occurs:Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name

Comment: @Banafsheh sorry bro i mistaken it was belongs to relation it can't be called as method. Now check the edit, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I should correct the name of a method in Product.php from subcats to subcat.

```
public function subcat(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcat::class);
    }
```

then use :
`@foreach($product as $item)
{{$item->subcat->name}}
@endforeach`